# When to use prop modifier in vue?

Tags: vue.js

When to use prop modifier in vue?

In vue document,I find the prop modifier in v-bind here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

my question is this:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

From the docs:

> Modifiers:
> .prop - Bind as a DOM property instead of an attribute (what’s the difference?). If the tag is a component then .prop will set the property on the component’s $el.

This is useful, because some HTML inputs can't receive a value as attribute, but need to be passed on the ref itself.

[See for example the `indeterminate` state of a checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_indeterminate.asp). Normally you'd need to do

```html
<template>
<!-- this doesn't work, because there's no indeterminate prop on the checkbox, it only exists on the DOM element -->
  <input type="checkbox" :indeterminate="indeterminateProp" /> 
</template>

<script>
beforeUpdate() {
  //set indeterminate directly on the dom element object
  // this is what you'd always have to do if v-bind.prop didn't exist
  this.$refs.myCheckbox.indeterminate = this.indeterminateProp;
}
</script>
```

and keep track of it manually outside of vue's reactivity system.

But thanks to .prop, you can just do

```html
<input type="checkbox" :indeterminate.prop="indeterminateProp"/>
```

Without having to play with lifecycle hooks.

So .prop basically tells vue "apply this value on the DOM node itself (the one you'd normally get from $refs) instead of trying to apply it as an attribute or property"

Comment: Is the  ```<input …> ``` missing ```ref=“ my-checkbox“```?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this modifier to pass a property to a component.

`<myComponent v-bind:<PropName></myComponend> is the same as <myComponent :<PropName>></myComponend>`

Checkout this link here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html.

Comment: my question is about this prop modifier<div v-bind:text-content.prop></div>

Comment: Each HTML Element has properties. For example a div element has a property text-content. To change this property you can use the prop.modifier .prop.